# Google App Engine Require Indexes for tests

Tags: python, google-app-engine, testing

I just got bit by my functional tests not using the same settings as my dev_appserver.  I currently run my dev_appserver (non-rel) with require_indexes.

How to I force my test bed to use the same setings?

I have tried using `SetupIndexes` but it did not "require" they be defined in my index.yaml.  I did not have the setting correct and as a result i can do any query I want.

i.e.

```
clz.testbed = Testbed()
clz.testbed.activate()
clz.testbed.init_memcache_stub()
clz.testbed.init_taskqueue_stub()
clz.testbed.init_urlfetch_stub()
clz.testbed.init_datastore_v3_stub(use_sqlite=True, datastore_file=somepath)
SetupIndexes('','')

model.objects().filter(x=1, y=2.....) #will work regardless of index defined.
```

but when the query executes on the server i get the

> NeedIndexError: This query requires a composite index that is not defined. You must update the index.yaml file in your application root.
>   The following index is the minimum index required:

Comment: It sounds like you have your functional tests instrumenting dev_appserver code directly to set up your test environment.  Is that the case?  If so, is there a reason you can't use ext.testbed?  (I'm not sure offhand how to get testbed to raise NeedIndexError based on index config, though it can be configured to use a specific datastore data file, so maybe it works given that...)  Also, by "objects()" do you mean the "all()" method of ext.db, or is this a different datastore API?

Comment: Not sure I follow?  I just ext testbed, but it does not require indexes.

Comment: So you're using `ext.testbed`, but it's raising `NeedIndexError` on every query?  Can you post some of your test set-up code?

Comment: Problem is my test code is *not* throwing any NeedIndex errors, only the app server is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding { "require_indexes" : True } as a keyword argument to init_datastore_v3_stub()

You can look through (and step through) the SDK code to see how that parameter is eventually passed into the datastore stub.

Comment: Your suggestion works, but its important to note that you have to set root_path as well, or you will have no indexes defined.