# Is there a way to configure tests for the Java Google App Engine SDK to fail if a compound index is needed?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, testing, google-cloud-datastore

I'd like to configure `LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig` such that queries will fail if a compound index is needed (e.g., a query with a sort on multiple properties). Is there a way to do this?

I tried `new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig().setNoIndexAutoGen(true)` but it had no effect.

(There is a [corresponding way to do this with the Python SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11622683/google-app-engine-require-indexes-for-tests).)

Answer (score 1):

I assume by "fail" you mean "throw an exception" or something similar.
If so, you should set the `autoGenerate` attribute in your `WEB-INF/datastore-indexes.xml` to false.

Example `WEB-INF/datastore-indexes.xml`:

```
<datastore-indexes autoGenerate="false">
</datastore-indexes>
```

Setting `autoGenerate` to false will make a query that requires a composite index throw an exception.
Example code:

```
try {
    Query q = new Query("Action")
            .addSort("encrypter", Query.SortDirection.ASCENDING)
            .addSort("requester", Query.SortDirection.ASCENDING)
            .addSort("time", Query.SortDirection.DESCENDING);

    //...snip...

} catch (Exception e) {
    log.severe(e.toString());
}
```

I tested this and got an exception logged as expected:

```
SEVERE: com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreNeedIndexException: Query com.google.appengine.api.datastore.dev.LocalCompositeIndexManager$IndexComponentsO
nlyQuery@f9f81ad3 requires a composite index that is not defined. You must update C:\appengine-java-sdk\dev\core1\war\WEB-INF\datastore-indexes.xml or enable au
toGenerate to have it automatically added.
The suggested index for this query is:
    <datastore-index kind="Action" ancestor="false" source="manual">
        <property name="encrypter" direction="asc"/>
        <property name="requester" direction="asc"/>
        <property name="time" direction="desc"/>
    </datastore-index>
```

For more information, see [datastore-indexes.xml reference](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/indexref).

Comment: Do you have an example of causing this failure in a unit test, though? I have this setting and it does cause queries to fail when running under the dev server, but tests that execute the same query don't fail. Perhaps there is something else I need to configure for tests to make them read the file.

Comment: For reproduction purposes, can you provide a minimal working example of how you wrote your test? Alternatively, you may want to try running your queries against XmlDocument objects defined such as this: 
    
    `XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
     doc.Load(xmlFilePath);`